# Visualise CSS selectors like :read-only in debug (F12 tools)

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Having

```css
:read-only, [readonly] {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h2>test</h2>
</form>
```

How can I detect, when debugging, say, in Chrome, that the `h2`(or `form`) field has an `:read-only` property (or other type of selector, like `:disabled`, etc.) set to `true`?

PS.

To clarify the question: the question is not about a CSS workaround for this concrete case, but rather a way to identify for a concrete element in devtools (F12 tools) if that element has or not some selectors, `:read-only` was an example among others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome DevTools this is visible in the "Styles" pane on the "Elements" tab. For your specific example the output looks like this:

[image: styles pane in elements tab - showing :read-only selector]

Note that matching part of the selector (`:read-only` in this case) is in black letters, while part that doesn't match (`[readonly]`) is greyed out.

---

More general solution to the problem, that allows you to check if any selector matches any DOM node, is to use [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). Simply inspect any DOM node and in the console execute `$0.matches(':some-selector')` (`$0` refers to last inspected element). This should work in all browsers.

[image: calling $0.matches in the DevTools console]

Comment: Thanks. The image you provided works only if the : read-only style is explicitly set in the CSS... But the "matches" workaroung is pretty cool, I didn't know it, thanks! Is a pity that is not displayed in the "Computed" tab of F12 Chrome tools... but is answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

At least in Chrome:

- `:read-only` selector applies to any noeditable elements (`<h2>` and `<p>` in snippet and `<html>` in your case)
- `[readonly]` selector only applies to elements with `readonly` attribute (`<p>` in snippet)

So you can use `readonly` attribute and `[readonly]` selector

```css
form :read-only {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
form [readonly] {
    border: 1px dashed #d00;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>test</h2>
  <input type="text" />
  <p readonly="readonly">test2</p>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. My question was not exactly about a CSS workaround, but  rather a way to identify for a concrete element in F12 tools if that element has or not some selectors, :read-only was an example among others...

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna delete the comments, just for the records it is: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312971

Comment: Should submit this feature idea to Chrome developpers too